# How to override joomla article pagination

Tags: articles

I'm using Joomla 3.5

I want to change style of my pagination. I already add pagination.php to my template folder and change the html and classes, it works at featured, category ... except article site.

Can you tell me how to override joomla article pagination?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the "Prev" / "Next" navigation, then that is set at plugins/content/pagenavigation/tmpl/default.php and can be overridden at templates/YOURTEMPLATE/html/plg_content_pagenavigation/

Further info from Joomla's documentation is available [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla).